# Date Form Element for Zend Framework Version 1.1.12

Tags: php, forms, date, zend-framework, element

Is there anything that I can use for Zend Framework version 1.1.12 that would be equivalent to the `Date Form Element` in Zend Framework version 2?

I can't find any homebrewed examples on the internet. Maybe someone knows someone that implemented this?

Comment: What You want to accomplish? A piece of code so we could help!

Comment: So far i know you have to write your custom form element to have a real date form element like zend 2. Otherwise you can treat them as text and have good javascript/jquery plugin for ui; manipulate it in your entity service with Datetime object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html show Zend Freamwork 1 standard elements. It does not provide a standard form element for date.

You have the following options:

1. Use [Zend_Form_Element_Text](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.text) field with date validation.
2. Make 3 drop downs for dd-mm-yyyy using [Zend_Form_Element_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.select)  elements.
3. Use [ZendX_JQuery Form Elements and Decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zendx.jquery.form.html) and make datepicker.